# Python - How to disable logging from a module imported from the parent directory?

Tags: python, logging, import, module, python-import

I have a file structure like this:

```
util/
└── utilA.py
src/
└── sublevel
    └── moduleB.py
```

In `moduleB` I use `from util.utilA import *` to import the functions from the util.

Inside `moduleB`, I want to disable the `logging.info()`'s in the util, but the following two lines wouldn't work and if I run `moduleB` I still see the logging generated from the functions in `utilA`:

```
logging.getLogger('util.utilA').propagate = False
logging.getLogger('util.utilA').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

I also tried `logging.getLogger('util')` and `logging.getLogger('utilA')` and neither of these worked.

One thing that also confuses me is that I used the same two lines (`logging.getLogger('pdfminer')...`) for another module [pdfminer](https://pypi.org/project/pdfminer/), and it successfully disabled the logging for that module. It just wouldn't work for my local `utilA`.

Can anyone help with this? Thank you!

Comment: What logger is utilA using? (it should be doing `logging.getLogger("something")`). Logging isn't based on module name. Its a common convention, but a module can create a logger of any name it wants.

Comment: @tdelaney `utilA` was using `logging.info('Something happened')`. After changing it to `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` and `logger.info('Something happened')` the problem was solved. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logging is based on the name you use when you get a logger, not the name of the module where the logging is performed. In particular, `logging.info()` uses the root logger. If you want to adjust logging of a given module, make sure that it is not using the root logger and use its `getLogger("somename")` logger name.